# NightwatchJS setup on local selenium grid

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid, nightwatch.js

I was not able to find a tutorial that uses nightwatch js and local selenium grid (stuck on how to update the nightwatch.conf.js file correctly). I want to run a nightwatch test using selenium grid but was not successful.

I followed this guide = https://www.guru99.com/introduction-to-selenium-grid.html (but I used nightwatch and not java)

Here is my setup (Machine A is on Virtual Box, I can ping vise-versa Windows 10 host):

- Machine A (hub) = Mint OS running selenium grid, ip = http://192.168.56.102/
- Machine B (node) = Windows 10 OS, ip = http://192.168.56.1

[image]

So only thing left to do is update the "nightwatch.conf.js" file and run the test

Here is what I updated:

[image]

This is the error that I get:

[image]

Comment: Try killing process at port `4444`

Comment: I'm using port 4444 to host the selenium grid.

Comment: I was able run it by changing the port number to 4445. But I got it working in a better state anyhow, forgot to update this post.

Answer (score 1):

This will work only when the selenium server is running in your machine. Grid is a setup where the server is running in a different machine. Below settings should work for you.

Replace `webdriver: {},` with below code and `selenium_host & selenium_port` from your current config.

```
selenium: {
  host: 192.168.56.102
  port: 4444
}
```

Please refer to `WebDriver Settings` section of official docs [here](https://nightwatchjs.org/gettingstarted/configuration/#base-settings).